# Azure Function Set Node Version

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to set the Node version for an Azure Function as per the documentation, but it seems to be stuck on version v6.11.2

I've tried setting this Application Setting:

```
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION
```

To be 8.1.4

I've also tried added this to be package.json:

```
"engines":{"node":"8.1.4"}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your Function App to v2 (currently in preview):

[image]

v1 is locked to `6.11.2` as per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management).

Comment: The beta button is greyed out for me - my runtime is  1.0.11559.0 (~1). What did you have as your FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION ? I've tried setting this to ~2 with little luck.

Comment: @Mattl It looks like they disabled possibility to switch for existing Function Apps and you have to create a new App to select v2.

Comment: OK that was the issue - I had to set the Runtime version and set the node version BEFORE deployiing my functions. To be fair to Microsoft - the Azure portal does say "Cannot Upgrade with Existing Functions". But I wish they had an easier way to switch Node versions like they do with PHP.

Comment: My attempt to combine the information from multiple sources on how to change Node.js version in Linux/Windows function apps via Portal/Azure CLI/ARM/Terraform/Powershell: https://www.maxivanov.io/change-nodejs-version-in-azure-functions/

Answer (score 6):

I just verified your steps. I created a new function app (consumption plan, windows based) and set the

```
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION
```

to be 8.1.4:

[image: Azure Function - Node version]

and then opened Kudu to run "node -v" to check the result

[image: Kudu - node version]

The runtime version this app is using is:

[image: Azure Function - runtime version]

Comment: I do exactly the same and I'm stuck at 6.11.2. What Runtime version are you using?

Comment: I updated my post with a screenshot of the runtime. Note: the app was created just a few minutes ago and has all its settings as default, only the node version changed.

Comment: Maybe an obvious thing but I'm just verifying it. Did you also save the application settings page, where you set the version? First enter 8.1.4 into the text box, then scroll to the top and press save?

Comment: Thanks for the help - yes I had saved the node version in application settings - I have no idea how you can get v8.1.4 from Runtime 1. I managed to get this to work by deleting all my functions and selecting beta so I'm on Runtime 2.x, setting the version as an app setting and then redeploying my functions!

Comment: What you're seeing in Kudu is not what a **v1** Function uses. v1 runtime compiles JavaScript down to C#, that's why it's locked to one Node version (just `context.log(process.version)` and you'll see). What you're seeing in Kudu is simply whatever would be used should you switch to the v2 runtime. **v2** actually calls into the _node_ binary (through something called a language worker) to run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration >> General settings

[image]